# How to change the menu like this?

Tags: menus

Here is my `wp_nav_menu`:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
            'link_before' => '<span><strong>',
            'link_after'  => '</strong></span>'
        ) );
```

I got `a` tag like this:

```
<a title="TITLE" href="..."><span><strong>LINK</strong></span></a>
```

But I actually need this:

```
<a href="..."><span><strong>LINK</strong>TITLE</span></a>
```

Is it possible to write a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom [walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker). Specifically, create a child class of [`Walker_Nav_Menu`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker_Nav_Menu). The only funciton you need to override is `start_el()`. Copy it wholesale into your class, and place the title where you want it. Then in your `wp_nav_menu` call, specify your walker.

```
<?php 
wp_nav_menu( array(
        'link_before' => '<span><strong>',
        'link_after'  => '</strong></span>',
        'walker'  => new My_Custom_Walker()
    ) );
```